# Плавное появление/закрытие формы

Tags: c#

Появилась задача, сделать так что бы форма плавно появилась и сразу же плавно исчезла, после этого перекинуло на 2 форму. Я решил использовать Opacity.
Вот код

```
Opacity = 0;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Tick += new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    if ((Opacity += 0.05d) == 1) timer.Stop();
});
timer.Interval = 100;
timer.Start();
```

Не получаеться только что бы он сразу начел исчезать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или запустите второй таймер после остановки первого, или добавьте флаг, который будет указывать на текущее действие - исчезновение или появление:

```
Opacity = 0;
bool fadingIn = true;

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Tick += new EventHandler((s, e1) =>
{
    if (fadingIn)
    {
        if ((Opacity += 0.05d) >= 1)
        {
            fadingIn = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ((Opacity -= 0.05d) <= 0)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
});
timer.Interval = 100;
timer.Start();
```